# Scrape table with no ids or classes using only standard libraries?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to scrape two pieces of data from a website:

https://www.moneymetals.com/precious-metals-charts/gold-price

Specifically I want the "Gold Price per Ounce" and the "Spot Change" percent two columns to the right of it.

Using only Python standard libraries, is this possible? A lot of tutorials use the HTML element id to scrape effectively but inspecting the source for this page, it's just a table. Specifically I want the second and fourth `<td>` which appear on the page.

Comment: no BeautifulSoup allowed?

Comment: @Cryptoharf84 I'd like to stay within Python standard libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do it with standard python libraries; ugly, but possible:

```
import urllib
from html.parser import HTMLParser

URL = 'https://www.moneymetals.com/precious-metals-charts/gold-price'

page = urllib.request.Request(URL)
result = urllib.request.urlopen(page)
resulttext = result.read()

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    gold = []

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.gold.append(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(str(resulttext))

for i in parser.gold:
    if 'Gold Price per Ounce' in i:
        target= parser.gold.index(i) #get the index location of the heading
        print(parser.gold[target+2]) #your target items are 2, 5 and 9 positions down in the list
        print(parser.gold[target+5].replace('\\n',''))
        print(parser.gold[target+9].replace('\\n',''))
```

Output (as of the time the url was loaded):

```
$1,566.70
8.65
0.55%
```